# How to programmatically download a file with IOS (iPhone, iPad)?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, ftp

Problem with downloading file from ftp server.

I try this below in my application.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@" ftp: // user : password @ host : port / path "];

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

This code is not work for me because I have a password of ftp like abc@des.

Can anybody help.!

Answer (score 0):

As there is no inbuilt lib for FTP try, [Karelia ConnectionKit](https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit) lib. It's simple to use and you can extend!

Comment: what? can you give brief explanation? @Retro

Comment: @BhargavNarola Just check the github page, there are sample for you

Comment: i want to make this in iphone application. @Retro